# Word for Excessive Care about Appearance?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I'm looking for a pejorative word that describes one who cares only about their own, and others' appearances, and cares nothing for personality to the point of obsession. Something that fits in like: "The son had inherited his mother's ______". Shallow is not the word I'm looking for - it wouldn't exactly fit in that sentence (and shallowness seems a bit awkward).

Vanity is the closest word I have to a fit, but it only describes an excessive care of oneself, and not others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *shallowness* is just fine, but here's an alternative:

***superficiality***

> 1 the quality or state of being superficial

(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superficiality)

"The son had inherited his mother's superficiality."

Comment: ‘Brittle superficiality’ might be good in the op’s sentence - giving the sense of the superficiality being a shell, like an eggshell that might break, if you pressed it just a little.

Answer (score 0):

Would facileness work?

Reference: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facile

Answer (score 0):

..."to the point of obsession", huh?

I suggest...

**[vestiphilia](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=KPnlCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT129&lpg=PT129&dq=vestiphilia&source=bl&ots=T7uoudU87g&sig=Fe0itllVxJdVV0vkeRfiTfQJ2tA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXnbKnoNrRAhVCpo8KHfCcD-k4ChDoAQgzMAU#v=onepage&q=vestiphilia&f=false)** (unnatural attraction to clothing)

Or if you're willing to berate them further:

**[cacophobia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cacophobia)** (phobia of ugliness)

Sorry, I can't find exact definitions that satisfy your requirements, but given the suffixes, the meanings are self-evident.

What I can provide, however, is evidence of usage:

- http://twitpic.com/photos/Vestiphilia
- http://vestiphilia.tumblr.com/
- http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cacophobia